# The meta favicon for UX is not grayscale

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is a teeny tiny little bug, but all the other meta sites seem to have a grayscale version of the favicon.  UX Meta, on the other hand, shares the same as the main site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.